# Foreach giving me data for the first loop and empty collection onwards

Tags: laravel, foreach

I have a foreach in my controller passed to the view:

```
 public function index()
{
    $budgets=\App\Budget::all();
    $transactions=\App\Transaction::select('transaction_ammount');

    foreach($budgets as $budget){
        $budgetThisCategory[$budget->id]=$transactions->whereMonth('transaction_date',Carbon::today()->format('m'))->where('category_id',$budget->category_id)->get();
    }

    return view('budgets.index',compact('budgets','id','transactions','budgetThisCategory'));
}
```

When I dd my view, I get the following:

```
array:2 [▼
  1 => Collection {#832 ▼
    #items: array:6 [▼
      0 => Transaction {#825 ▶}
      1 => Transaction {#826 ▶}
      2 => Transaction {#827 ▶}
      3 => Transaction {#828 ▶}
      4 => Transaction {#829 ▶}
      5 => Transaction {#830 ▶}
     ]
   }
   2 => Collection {#868 ▼
     #items: []
   }
 ]
```

So I only get my first foreach collection but not my second one. There is data in the second one. Indeed if I change in my controller and add a orderbydesc('$budget_id') I will get this second collection, but not the first one.

What am I doing wrong? I am quite new to this, and I am sure that the way to solve this is simple. But I do not really know what's the problem.

Comment: why you don't try to use eloquent relationships? Instead of doing that thing? https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships#one-to-one

Answer (score 0):

Matthew thanks for the answer. You have put me in a path that I didn't know that it existed. I have changed all that foreach into a complety different thing, more beautiful and simple. Plus I have added some functionality. I suposed that there are better ways to do it. But I am really happy of where I have arrived.

```
$budgets=\App\Budget::get();

    foreach($budgets as $budget){
        $budgetCount[$budget->id]=$budget->find($budget->id)->transactions()->whereMonth('transaction_date',Carbon::today()->format('m'))->count();
        $budgetSum[$budget->id]=$budget->find($budget->id)->transactions()->whereMonth('transaction_date',Carbon::today()->format('m'))->sum('transaction_ammount');
    }
```